# console.writeline not working/not updating, Input and Output don't match

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

```
namespace MyFirstProject
{
    class program
    {
        static void main (string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
            Console.WriteLine("This should be gray ");
            Console.WriteLine("This should be blue.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I am entering this but when I hit F5 I get the output "Hello, World !"

Comment: Please look at the preview of your question before submitting and don't submit if the formatting is a mess.

Comment: Is your project actually building? I suspect not, and it's an old version of the compiled EXE that's being run.

Comment: The first line of that code indicates that you are targeting .NET 6 and you are using top-level statements, which means no namespace, no class and no method declaration. You just provide the body of the `Main` method. That's why there was nothing but a `Console.ReadLine` call in the first place.

Comment: oh ok so i just directly start writing the code instead of declaring anything ?

Comment: and also if i am using .NET 6 then i never need to declare anything ?

Comment: It's not that you don't need to declare anything. You still need to declare variables, methods, etc. It's just that, in the Program.cs file itself, you only need to provide the body of the `Main` method and the rest is implicit. You should do some research on top-level statements to learn how they work. There's a box you can check when you create a .NET 6 project if you don't want to use top-level statements. I'm guessing that there's something you can do to change it after the fact but I don't know what that is. You could create two projects and compare to find out.